# SQL averaging update query

Tags: sql, sql-update, average

I got an update query that I have to do and I'm struggling with it.

I have 3 columns, ID, Income, AverageIncome.

- ID: string but is ordered alphabetically.
- AverageIncome-. averageIncome of the previous 10 Income entries.

All the values of the AverageIncome are incorrect and I need to update them to be correct.

Any Tip?

Thanks!

Comment: Query or queries that you have tried? Always add this information to your question, when posting on StackOverflow.

Comment: What database are you using?  And, how do you define "previous 10 income entries"?  SQL tables represent unordered sets, so there is no concept of "previous 10 entries" unless you have a column specifying the ordering.

Comment: I'd wonder why you would store that average income.  You should have effective datetime as a column; you could calculate average income over time for any number of points that way.  Sounds like a badly designed schema.

Comment: ive been quite lost about how to reference different entries for each average... I was thinking that using a temp table might work

Comment: the entries are ordered already by their IDs so the average income is the average of the 10 previous income entries, determined by the IDs

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: ...What the heck are your ids?  (What do they represent?)  In almost no situation is partitioning by an id actually useful - you want to calculate based on something that has a natural range for that (like time).  Usually, it's best to regard ids as something akin to memory addresses - the values are pointers to the records, but have no relation to the actual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL syntax, and assuming that the order is defined by the `id` column:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_table_copy AS SELECT * FROM my_table;

UPDATE my_table t
SET average_income = (SELECT AVG(tc.income) 
                    FROM my_table_copy tc
                    WHERE tc.id < t.id
                    ORDER BY tc.id DESC
                    LIMIT 10
                    );  

DROP TABLE my_table_copy;
```

Of course you will have to make sure that `CREATE TABLE` and `UPDATE` execute atomically, i.e. without any modification of the data between one an the other.

Also keep in mind that this is not a very good design, as other users already pointed out. You will have redundancy in your data. You might be better off with a view in this case.